# What are the steps of putting a video into a SQL database and retrieving it from a web application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, file-upload

I'm developing a website in VB.Net that allows a user to submit a form that can include a video. In speaking with our server administrator, there are no write permissions for files, so I was instructed to put any videos into the MS SQL database.

I know this is inefficient, but they don't seem to care.

I *think* any type of file can be stored in a database by specifying the field in the DB as varbinary and then converting the file to a bitstring before uploading. But I have no idea how to actually do this, nor have I been able to find any direction from the MS site that isn't simply uploading an Image.

So what I need to know or find a resource for is:

- The steps involved with accessing file chosen by the user and converting it to a useable data type to stick in the db.
- The steps involved with pulling that video back from the DB and displaying it for the user in the db.

I wish I could simply tell all the users to upload it to Youtube and then just use the link, but that isn't an option either.

If I need more clarification, I can do my best.

Thanks!

Comment: google is your friend: google "store video in MS SQL database" = https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=storing+video+in+ms+sql+database&oq=storing+video+in+ms+sql+database&gs_l=hp.3...8050.10499.1.10760.11.9.2.0.0.2.149.1047.1j8.9.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.yLFy13PihMg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.b2I&fp=897ba9997041d6f1&ion=1&biw=1920&bih=1053

Comment: Try this, although I would recommend storing the file on the file system. Can they create a user that could save to the file system so then you have control: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21480/Video-Uploader-Control-for-SQL-Server

Comment: I have found both of those before, but as I'm unfamiliar with c#, I was hoping to find the equivalent in VB.

Comment: it's not a perfect solution but you could use a c# converter, I recommend doing one or two functions at a time: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: Since you're using SQL 2008 you should look at FileStream for storing these in the DB